# How to get the length of repeated numbers column wise?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the length of repeated numbers in Python Numpy. For example, let's consider a simple ndarray

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
])
```

The first column has `[0, 1, 0, 1]`, the position of `1` is `1`, now start counting from there, we get `ones = 2` and `zeros = 1`. So I have to start counting `ones` and `zeros` when `1` is encountered (starting position).

so the answer for `a` would be

```
ones = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
zeros = [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Can any one please help me out?

**Update**

3D array:

```
a = np.array([
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ],
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ]
])
```

The expected output should be

```
ones = [
         [2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0],
         [1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
       ]
zeros = [
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]
        ]
```

Comment: Would it always be 0 and 1 in `a` or could there be other numbers too?

Comment: @Divakar its always 0 or 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With focus on performance, here's one generic approach for ndarrays -

```
ones_count = a.sum(-2)
zeros_count = (a.shape[-2] - ones_count - a.argmax(-2))*a.any(-2)
```

One alternative to get `zeros_count` with selections using `np.where`, would be -

```
zeros_count = np.where(a.any(-2),a.shape[-2] - ones_count - a.argmax(-2),0)
```

**Sample runs**

`2D` case :

```
In [60]: a
Out[60]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])

In [61]: ones_count = a.sum(-2)
    ...: zeros_count = (a.shape[-2] - ones_count - a.argmax(-2))*a.any(-2)
    ...: 

In [62]: ones_count
Out[62]: array([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1])

In [63]: zeros_count
Out[63]: array([1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

3D case :

```
In [65]: a = np.array([
    ...:     [
    ...:         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ...:         [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ...:         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ...:         [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ...:     ],
    ...:     [
    ...:         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ...:         [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    ...:         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    ...:         [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ...:     ]
    ...: ])

In [66]: ones_count = a.sum(-2)
    ...: zeros_count = (a.shape[-2] - ones_count - a.argmax(-2))*a.any(-2)
    ...: 

In [67]: ones_count
Out[67]: 
array([[2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0],
       [1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]])

In [68]: zeros_count
Out[68]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]])
```

and so on for higher dim arrays.

Comment: So if I have a 3D array I just have to define a function and put them in a loop. right? or is there an efficient way?

Comment: @akshay I would think you just need to change all those `0's` to `1's`, i.e. `a.sum(1)`, `a.shape[1]` and `a.argmax(1)` depending on how you interpret the `2D` slices out of that 3D array.

Comment: @akshay Updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Does number `-2` depend on the length of 3d array?

Comment: @akshay `-2` means along the columns irrespective of the number of dims in the input array. That way, the code should work without any change on any ndarray of any no. of dims of any shape.